# How can we get a list of URLS recently visited by an android device? And the amount of time spent on a URL?

Tags: permissions, logging, data-monitoring, resource-monitoring

I am trying to figure out how much data collection for time tracking can be automatically done on android devices.

So basically I want to collect the amount of time that a user spends on youtube, facebook etc. It is possible to log the currently running activities, which can be used to figure out roughly for how much time a particular app, e.g. FBMessenger/WhatsApp, was opened. But, I want to also track the browsing pattern of a user in an app-agnostic way.

There are a few parental control apps that promise to do this such as:

```
https://www.qustodio.com/en/family/how-it-works/
```

And I want to figure out how they might be doing so, which api/permissions allows for this level of access?

UPDATE: For example the `Net-Nanny` android [FAQ](https://www.netnanny.com/mobile/faqs) says that

```
Once those settings are done Net Nanny will Initialize and invite you to
browse the Web! – This will be done thru the Net Nanny Browser.
All other browsers will be blocked.
```

This is a bad solution since this presumes that a user has to change his/her behavior in order for me to monitor them. I don't want to block anything for the user, only create usage stats.

I also don't want to install a VPN server if it can be avoided because it gives a persistent [warning message to the user](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/2k1sxa/android_50_new_vpn_notification).

Comment: As a side question: did you actually think that your users may not like you to spy on them?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman There are legit use cases of such "spying" such as parental controls, or research into HCI. In any case I am currently trying to figure out capability not morality.

Comment: +1 to your comment, but I have no idea as to how implement it.